# How to create TOC or index using the Flying Saucer project?

Tags: java, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

I convert HTML files to PDF format using [The Flying Saucer Project](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//). This are documents containing repetitive information - premises and their addresses, let's call them elements. At the end of a document I need to create an index. Each index entry should have a page number referring to the page where element was added. The number of elements that can fit on one page will vary.

How can I create a document index? Or how can I get notified while library adds certain type of HTML element to the PDF document?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

In CSS

```
ol.toc a::after {  content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href), page);}
```

In HTML

```
<h1>Table of Contents</h1>
<ol class='toc'>
<li><a href=\"#chapter1\">Loomings</a></li>
<li><a href=\"#chapter2\">The Carpet-Bag</a></li>
<li><a href=\"#chapter3\">The Spouter-Inn</a></li>
</ol>

<div id="chapter1">Loomings</div>
```

Comment: The CSS is missing an argument. Use: `ol.toc a::after {  content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href url), page, decimal);}` See [Link](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#target-counter) for more info.

Comment: apparently the pageCount does not show up. It is only generating a list with a clickable link to navigate to the corresponding content.

Comment: it works when just using `attr(href)` instead of `attr(href url)` and without `leader('.')` But then you get the page number right after the Link-Name.

Answer (score 1):

I found possible answer. You have to start playing with `org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox` class. A method `public void layout(LayoutContext c, int contentStart)` is used to place properly any HTML element in the PDF document. This method iterates through an element a few times. After the last iteration a valid page number is set.

If you mark an element you want to index, by for example using a class attribute, then you can get a page number using following code:

```
String cssClass = getElement().getAttribute("class");
if(!cssClass.equals("index")) {
    int pageNumber = c.getRootLayer().getPages().size();
    /* ... */
}
```